# How to store daat into localStorage in laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel

I have this API controller receive data from URL and store it into the database I would like to store it into the local storage of the browser too. what should I do?
this my controller

```
public function storePayment(Request $request)
{
    // revice data from application token_id => userCardName user_phone
    // Request Status
    $payment = new Payment();
    $payment->token_id = $request->token_id;
    $payment->status = $request->status;
    $payment->request_id = $request->request_id;
    $payment->user_id = $request->user_id;
    $payment->user_phone = $request->user_phone;
    $payment->price = $request->price;
   // echo $token_id;


    $payment->save();

        return '<script>

        localStorage.setItem("user_id",$user_id);
        localStorage.setItem("request_id",$request_id);
        localStorage.setItem("price",$price);
        localStorage.setItem("user_phone",$user_phone);


      </script>';




}
```

Comment: Where are `$user_id`, `$request_id`, `$price` and `$user_phone` defined? And please note that they won't be expanded using single quotes

Comment: Saving to the database is working fine I want to save the same values  into the local storage of the browser

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question

Comment: Where should I define them?

Comment: ... before you assign them. Or use the ones you already have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the quotes due to a string parsing issue.

```php
  return "<script>

        localStorage.setItem('user_id', {$payment->user_id});
        localStorage.setItem('request_id', {$payment->request_id});
        localStorage.setItem('price', {$payment->price});
        localStorage.setItem('user_phone', {$payment->user_phone});


      </script>";
```

Comment: gave me this Undefined variable: user_id after I have changed the quotes

Comment: Unless there's some magic going on in the background that I'm not aware of none of those variables are defined

Comment: how to define them in the controller ?

Comment: @الحجاجعبدالله That's basic PHP, please read about [Variable Basics](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php)

Comment: man, you have many more issues there, I update the answer